# angular 6 mat-dialog scroll down to bottom automatically

Tags: angular

I have an issue with scroll  down automatically when open the mat-dialog.
I have 2 buttons that cause the the problem (I assume) but I didn't figure out what to do to resolve the issue.

The component.ts code :

```
 openDialog(): void {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FileBrowserComponent, { 
       height: '600px',
       width: '700px',
});
```

The dialog html code :

```
<div class="container">

<div class="img" *ngFor="let element of fileElements">
    <img src="{{assetsFullUrl(element.name)}}" alt="{{element.name}}" (dblclick)="selectedImage===true">
</div>

</div>

<vaadin-upload target="http://localhost:3000/assets/upload" method="POST" 
accept="image/*"></vaadin-upload>

<div class="buttons">
<button mat-raised-button color='primary' type="button" (click)="add()">Save</button>
<button mat-raised-button color='basic' type="button" (click)="cancel()">Cancel</button>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Could you please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) e.g. using [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content), the first tabable element will be focused. You can assign `tabindex="-1"` to prevent the buttons from getting focused

```
<button mat-raised-button tabindex="-1">Not Tabbable</button>
```

Comment: Yes that what I searched.Thanks a lot!

Comment: This might not work if you have more than one tabbable element on the page and this prevents accessiblity on the the button. The other answer works better, `autofocus: false` serves well.

Answer (score 36):

Try adding "autoFocus: false" to your code:

`openDialog(): void {
let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(FileBrowserComponent, { 
       height: '600px',
       width: '700px',
       autoFocus: false,
});`

Comment: thanks, that helped me, in another case, but really helped !

Comment: Thank you sir! I was looking for hours on how to set the focus on the dialog.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Tested with Angular 15. I had the same problem as original poster.

But adding `autoFocus: false` in dialog call, as suggested by van_Skyr, helped.