# MatDialogRef textarea scrolls to bottom

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-dynamic-components

I have an app where i use `MatDialogRef` to open a component as a dialog.

The dialog shows a long text, but for some reason, the textarea scrolls to the bottom. 
This does not happen when it's not a dynamically created component.

Heres an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialogref-textarea-scroll-issue

I hope someone can explain whats happening and how to fix it, so the `textarea`  stays in the top of the scroll.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [**`@angular/material`**](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview#dialog-content) dialog docs:

> Once a dialog opens, the dialog will automatically focus the first tabbable element.
>
> You can control which elements are tab stops with the `tabindex` attribute

Just add a `tabindex=0` on the modal div:

```
<div class="dialog" tabindex="0">
    <textarea class="texta" [(ngModel)]="data"></textarea>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/matdialogref-textarea-scroll-issue-fix?file=src/app/dialog/dialog.component.html) for your ref.
>
> Here's another thread for your ref:
> [angular 6 mat-dialog scroll down to bottom automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53029780/angular-6-mat-dialog-scroll-down-to-bottom-automatically)

Comment: Thank you for the help and the explanation!